# Prestashop gives 404 after shipping info step

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404, prestashop

I really hope that someone can help me with this issue I am having. I think the easiest way to explain it is how to reproduce it. My site is at www.jiblab.dk

- A customer puts any item in cart
- Goes to checkout
- Press continue(the green button that says "videre")
- Gets to shipping-info-step
- Fills in personal info (not login or register)
- Press next (green button that says "næste")
- website gives 404 page not found.
- If I go back and try again I do not get the 404 again.
- Empty cookies and it all happens again.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Any code? What have you tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything specific yet. I am unable to locate the cause of the error. What code would you like me to fetch?

Comment: I just saw they have an issue on this on their bugtracker. However, a fix isn't due before february. Is there a redirect workaround I could do? The site just needs to retry the form-submit after 404 is shown :/

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with success but i stopped at paypal ;-) 
( look the account email is dsqdsq@dsqsdq.fr )

It was On Firefox.

Did you try with others browsers ?
Did you try to desactivate the one step checkout  for tests ?